# How to perform long image image processing quickly

Tags: numpy, opencv, for-loop, image-processing, nearest-neighbor

I'm doing the task of classifying every pixel of an image through the nearest neighbor classifier. I manually give the centroid, RGB values, and threshold. Then I calculate the Euclidean distance of each pixel's RGB values with the centroid. If that distance is more than the threshold, I classify that pixel as black and retain its value otherwise.

The code I am using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
frame=cv2.imread('coloredChips.png')
thres=100
cen_r=111
cen_g=10
cen_b=10
mask=frame
def dist(r,g,b):
    global cen_r,cen_g,cen_b
    return np.linalg.norm(np.array((r,g,b)) - np.array((cen_r,cen_g,cen_b)))
for i in range(391):
    for j in range(518):
        if dist(frame[i,j,2],frame[i,j,1],frame[i,j,0])>thres:
            mask[i,j,2]=0
            mask[i,j,1]=0
            mask[i,j,0]=0
plt.imshow(mask)
```

But on 1 image it takes 2-3 seconds to perform this task.
Next, I did it on a live video. It's obvious that the video is now laggy with each frame taking 3 seconds to process. Is there any faster way to do this? Something that can produce 10 frames per second.

I have tried calculating distance through `np.sqrt` but the problem still remains.

Comment: Avoid type-checking infested loops, favor vectorized operations provided by either OpenCV or Numpy.

Comment: Please share your input and output images. Thank you.

Comment: Don't take the square root of your distance, take the square of your threshold - it's much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Fast sketch:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
frame = cv2.imread('coloredChips.png')

# Define the threshold and center point
thres = 100
cen_r = 111
cen_g = 10
cen_b = 10

# Compute the distance between each pixel and the center point
distances = np.linalg.norm(frame - np.array((cen_r, cen_g, cen_b)), axis=-1)

# Create the mask by selecting pixels that meet the threshold condition
mask = np.zeros_like(frame)
selected_pixels = np.where(distances <= thres) # copy only where under threshold
mask[selected_pixels] = frame[selected_pixels]
# or: mask = np.where(distances > thres, 0, frame)
# hard to say which one faster

# Display the masked image
cv2.imshow('Masked Image', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Fill free to ask related questions about this code.

Comment: Just a heads up. You are using matplotlib to _plot_ an image read by OpenCV. Generally, your image channels will be reversed.

Comment: changed to `cv2.imshow`, but there may be problems in case of running in colab. But it's another topic.

Comment: This was just an example code that shows my problem. I'm not using matplotlib or opencv to show the image. I'm showing live feed on a tkinter window. I'll try this method and get back to you later.